# Notification does not returns to an activity with the name ExitActivity

Tags: android, notifications

I came across a strange behavior. When the name of the activity to return from the notification is ExitActivity, my notification does not returns to it upon tapping the notification, but when I change the name of the activity to Exit2Activity or Exit_Activity it works.

It is further strange, because it happens on a real device only (Galaxy) but it works fine on the emulator.

Strange.
Posted just in case somebody else encounters this kind of behavior, so to save him/her few hours of frustration.

Comment: Are you asking something or telling something to us?

Comment: I am more telling, but it is also a question why does it happen?